# Как создать блоки в html5

Tags: html, html5, css

Если после прочтения сообщения покажется, что более безумного вопросы видеть Вам ещё не приходилось видеть, не пугайтесь, я просто никогда не сталкивался с html5 и css...
Но мне нужно сделать несколько страничек с кнопками и я решив, что справлюсь, отправился на поиски в инеты, но после пару часов так ничего и не понял. Вопросов у меня много, но все на разные темы, так что начну по порядку - как мне сделать полоску определённого цвета сверху, как на этом сайте в самом верху серо-синяя? И я над этой полоской хочу разместить кнопки, по этому спрошу сразу - чем является эта полоска? Она просто нарисована или это фон какого-то блока, в который помещены кнопки?

Comment: возьмите бутстрап и не мучайтесь, в бутсрапе эта полоска называется navbar

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html5 - вот здесь много узнаете об этом

Comment: @eicto: Спасибо за совет! Очень понравилось. Для меня самое оно.

Comment: @soledar10: Спасибо! Читал, но что-то не получалось..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте фреймворки [Semantic ui](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html) или [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: Скачайте себе дистрибутивы и посмотрите примеры внутри.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev: Спасибо! А Вы случаем не знаете, что лучше первое или второе?

Comment: Сначала думал - бутстрап, но потом больше понравился semantic ui - у них хоть и приходится грозди классов к тегам прицеплять, но зато как удобно код читать: это выровнено по центру на 5/4 страницы, крупным шрифтом.... Все классы - семантические, "говорящие".